# Drag button in iphone

Tags: objective-c

I am new to iphone application.And in my app I want to drag a button from one position to another.and when I drop it, it must stay there.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at UIGestureRecognizer in the documentation : 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html